# Lucky Buddha Beer

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, liquor-beer

does anyone know if the beer lucky buddha beer is kosher? it is a beer made in china? does anyone know if it has been certified kosher by any establishment?
Please let me know

Comment: the importer of the beer has confirmed that the ingredients are as follows : malt, hops, rice and water. Does this mean it is kosher???

Comment: Was it used for avoda zara though given its name?

Comment: @CashCow, seems more to making fun of the Avoda Zara to me.

Comment: Generally, it's pretty accepted that unflavored beer (hops, malt, water, yeast) doesn't require an explicit hashgacha, but most people require one for flavored beers. The addition of rice into the mix is an interesting twist, but I'm not certain if we would treat the rice like we do the malt (no hashgacha needed) or since it's a deviation from the norm we would require full supervision.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, also most of the statements about things being fine without certification are dependent on their country of manufacture. Standard manufacturing procedure in China may (or may not) be different.

Comment: @Yishai very fair point. Most beer I tend to encounter tends to be European or american, both of which are considered okay via the guidelines I stated. Many local restaurants under supervision offer Chinese and Japanese beers, so...

Comment: Sort of related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4935/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27165/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36172/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43794/

Comment: Close-voter: This question does not ask what the asker should do, personally, and is therefore no more of a request for pesak than any other Halacha question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I am not the close voter, but "please let me know" ?

Comment: @YeZ http://is.gd/ocmon